# How to create a thumbnail from the middle of a video with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, thumbnails

Is there a way to grab a video thumbnail in FFmpeg?

I'd like to grab the middle-most frame as the video and use that as the thumbnail. Video duration is unknown.

The ability to specify the dimensions of the thumbnail would also be helpful.

Answer (score 11):

One line command :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -ss `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d , | awk -F ':' '{print ($3+$2*60+$1*3600)/2}'` output.jpg
```

The subcommand get the total duration of the input video

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d ,
```

And pipe it to `awk` to compute duration/2 like this

```
echo '00:01:30.000' | awk -F ':' '{print ($3+$2*60+$1*3600)/2}'
```

So it give this among of seconds to -ss option and it's done.

If you would like to specify the size, add -s option like that WxH where W and H are integer values (ex: -s 800x600 or -s svga) or read the ffmpeg man page to see other available options or format.

Comment: `-vcodec mjpeg -an -f rawvideo` is not needed when your output is just a `.jpg` file. I'd actually recommend outputting to PNG instead and doing the compression later.

Comment: The `ffmpeg` output is only for informative purposes only and not intended for parsing, so therefore processing it may be considered fragile. Use `ffprobe` to get the duration instead. See [FFmpeg Wiki: FFprobe Tips](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Duration).

Answer (score 8):

Here's a method using:

- `ffprobe` to get the duration
- [`bc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_(programming_language)) to calculate half the duration
- `ffmpeg` to make the thumbnail image

Example:

```
input=input.mp4; ffmpeg -ss "$(bc -l <<< "$(ffprobe -loglevel error -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration "$input")*0.5")" -i "$input" -frames:v 1 half.png
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, always use the latest version of FFmpeg.

If you have access to PHP, your question is perfectly answered on Stack Overflow: [Use FFMpeg to get middle frame of a video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066638/use-ffmpeg-to-get-middle-frame-of-a-video)

```
$output = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i {$path}");
preg_match('/Duration: ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([^ ,])+/', $output, $matches);
$time = str_replace("Duration: ", "", $matches[0]);
$time_breakdown = explode(":", $time);
$total_seconds = round(($time_breakdown[0]*60*60) + ($time_breakdown[1]*60) + $time_breakdown[2]);
shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y  -i {$path} -f mjpeg -vframes 1 -ss " . ($total_seconds / 2) . " -s {$w}x{$h} {$output_filename}";
```

What it'll do is just extract the duration from FFmpeg's output and use that to determine the timecode of the middle frame.

You can easily adapt that to other shells, and simply insert into the following command, where the middle frame is roughly at `534` seconds:

```
ffmpeg -y  -i input.mp4 -f mjpeg -vframes 1 -ss 534 thumbnail.jpg
```

You can always change the size with `-s 480x320` or similar, depending on how big you want it, inserted somewhere after the `-i input.mp4` option.

---

The above solution is a little inaccurate. It'll immediately give you a result but you can't specify which frame you want. If you already know the exact frame you want to extract, use the `select` filter, e.g. with the frame number `12345`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v select="eq(n\,12345)" -vframes 1 thumbnail.jpg
```

Note that this command can take a while since it needs to skip to the specified frame before it can extract it.

Comment: An alternate way to specify thumbnail dimensions - this example crops it to a 4:3 aspect ratio: `ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "crop=(ih*4/3):ih" -f mjpeg -vframes 1 -ss 534 thumbnail.jpg`

Comment: Is there a way to skip the "waiting" part? Fast-forward to the specified frame/time ?

Comment: @Samson Which solution exactly are you talking about? If you specify `-ss` before `-i`, seeking should be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
$currentVideoDuration =  shell_exec("$ffmpeg -i $videoPath 2>&1 | grep Duration");
  $actualDuration = substr($currentVideoDuration, 11, 12);
  $arrayWithHoursMinsAndSecs = explode(":", $actualDuration);
  $thisVideoDurationInSeconds = $arrayWithHoursMinsAndSecs[2] + $arrayWithHoursMinsAndSecs[1]*60 + $arrayWithHoursMinsAndSecs[0]*3600;
  $halfVideoDuration = $thisVideoDurationInSeconds/2;
  echo 'midpoint of this video: '. $halfVideoDuration;
  echo shell_exec("$ffmpeg -i $videoPath -y -ss 00:00:$halfVideoDuration -vframes 1 thumbnail.png 2>&1");
```

replace $videopath with the path to your video

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is :

```
 ffmpeg -i l1.mp4 -ss 00:00:14.435 -vframes 1 out.png
```

Comment: This looks a lot like [Prometee’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/477340/150988#763185) and [LordNeckbeard’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/477340/150988#915369) except you assume that the user already knows the length of the video (the question says that they don’t) and you don’t explain anything.

Comment: I gives just example, if no need time then try this ffmpeg -i l1.mp4  -vframes 1 out11.jpg

Answer (score -1):

This bash command works like a charm:

```
avconv -i 'in.mpg' -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo \
-s 420x300 -ss `avconv -i in.mpg 2>&1 | grep Duration \
| awk '{print $2}' | tr -d , \ 
| awk -F ':' '{print ($3+$2*60+$1*3600)/2}'` out.jpg
```

Comment: My god that's complicated